# Problem with Chrome and Google web fonts. Showing different output from Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-webfonts

I am using google web fonts for a page of mine, but I get a different result in Chrome from Firefox. Firefox's result is the correct and I don't have a clue why Chrome does this problem.

The code is simple

```
intro { font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size:33px; line-height:38px; color: #404040;}
logo { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300italic&subset=greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&subset=greek,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<logo>Logo goes here</logo>
<br><br>
<intro>Text goes right here</intro>
```

or as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/KSVTA/ or http://fiddle.jshell.net/KSVTA/show/ Chrome does not make use of Open Sans Condensed.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Sans Condensed is defined with `font-style: italic`, so you'd need to apply that style to your second text as well: http://jsfiddle.net/KSVTA/1/.

The CSS file of that font is as follows:

```
@media screen {
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Cond Light Italic'), local('OpenSans-CondensedLightItalic'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v3/jIXlqT1WKafUSwj6s9AzV1qvxng10Zx7YyzmqNB25XX3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff') format('woff');
}
}
```

You can see the italic definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your "intro" the CSS property

```
font-style: italic;
```

then it works fine in Chrome.

Also, you may want to [read this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197006/is-it-possible-to-make-up-html-tags) about non-standard HTML tags.